# Deletar dados automaticamente do BD no dia seguinte

Tags: android, firebase

estou com essa dúvida e não sei como desenvolver, vocês poderiam me ajudar nesse caso?

O usuário colocaria por exemplo:

Trânsito na rua A horário 17 horas

e salvaria no banco.

No dia seguinte, esse registro teria que seria apagado automaticamente, já que essa ocorrência foi no dia anterior.

Estou usando banco firebase, e todos que tiverem usando o aplicativo, iria ver essa mensagem em uma listview.

Comment: somente com o firebase vai ser meio dificil. Procura por `cronjob` ou `crontab`

Comment: Você pode utilizar o [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html?utm_campaign=culture_education_functions_en_06-29-17&utm_source=Firebase&utm_medium=yt-desc) para isso.